# Custom Table View cell that autoresizes like twitter, facebook, etc

Tags: swift, tableview, autoresize

I'm building an app that'll include a newsfeed like viewcontroller using a tableView and custom cell (see image for the custom cell layout). The two items in the view controller that'll have a dynamic height are the UIImageview and the textlabel with numberoflines set to 0. How can i have the custom cell resize based on the label's number of lines and whether or not an image is included

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXwuH.png)

Comment: To make self sized cells of a table view... 1. Make sure the custom table view cell's constraints capable enough to calculate its content size 2. Say tableView.estimatedRowHeight = <An estimated height for cell>
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension

Comment: Adding to @Dipika's comment and your second part of the question where cell should automatically resize when image is present or not - This can be achieved by using stack view with four side constraints and setting imageView.isHidden whenever image is nil makes, cell adjust automatically (provided automaticDimension is set).